# Surface Tension of Water and Breaking through that surface tension

Tags: water

I know that the high surface tension of water makes it relatively more difficult for light objects to break through the surface (i.e. it's why insects can "walk" on water).  So that seems to work when an object moves from the air into the water (submerged).  But what about from the other direction?  By that I mean, an object trying to break through the surface of the water but moving from a submerged location to one above the water (in air).  In this scenario, is it also relatively more difficult to break through water than if an object was trying to break through ethanol, for example, from a submerged location?

Comment: Yes.$\mathstrut$

Comment: It all depends on the nature of the sample.

Comment: Notice small bubbles do not immediately break through the surface.